# What is the way to navigate in Android app

Tags: android, navigation

I'm developing a Twitter client for Android and I would like to know which is the better way to build my app.
I want to have a listview that, when clicked, calls another listview to see details and so on but I would also like to be able to go back in my previous list.

What is the best way to do this in Android? At every click, I create a new intent associated with an activity and I do `startActivity(intent)` so that I can be able to go back with the Back button of Android.

Is it a good way or is there a better approach? I would like to navigate onward and backward of n-levels

Answer (score 1):

The way to navigate back in Android is by launching the Activity intent waiting for a result [Doc link](http://bit.ly/9l7iN8) and then when you need to go back from the new Activity simply finish it [Doc link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())

Answer (score 0):

Calling finish() in an Activity closes it and returns to the previous one. You can call in on a button click or similar.